# Given an index and an array, return the value of the array with the given index

Tags: javascript

```
function valueAtus(arr, index){
    const indexs = arr.findIndex(x => x == Math.floor(index))
    arr.
}
console.log(valueAtus([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7], 10 / 2))
```

Comment: Function to do what looks like accessing an array in the usual manner?

Comment: First, please see [ask]. Second, see NickSlash's comment above. Third, it's "[*indices*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/indices#English)", not "*indexs*".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use ordinary array index access `[]` and round down your possible index with `Math.floor()`:

```js
let myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7];

console.log(myArray[Math.floor(10 / 2)]);
```

Comment: You may want to reword this. "Simply use Math.floor" shouldn't be the takeaway here as the OP is already using it.

Comment: @Andy In original question he was not.